# Difference between src_postgres and dbConnect function to connect R with postgres

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql

what is the difference between `src_postgres` and `dbConnect` function? Both can be used to connect R with postgres using the RPosgresql package. In my experiments I only could use src_postgres to **read** and **dbConnect** to write to the database.

When I tried it in different combinations I only received errors.

This seems fairly strange to me.

Comment: I'm confused. Were you aware that those functions are from two totally different packages?

Comment: not really. But I am confused that only one can read and the other one can write to the DB.

Comment: And as far as I know RPostgresql loads DBI and is only used as a wrapper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`src_postgres` is a function for creating a connection to a PostgreSQL database from the **dplyr** package. The **RPostgreSQL** package implements a method for the generic `dbConnect` from the **DBI** package. `src_postgres` calls `dbConnect` from **RPostgreSQL** (I assume).

The generic connection object returned by `dbConnect` is meant to be an open ended interface for sending SQL queries to the data base. This means you could feed it any `select`, `update`, `insert`, `delete`, etc. query that you like.

`src_postgres` is part of the higher level interface to working with data from databases that Hadley built in **dplyr**. The `src_*` functions connect to a db and then the `tbl` functions specify a more specific data source (table, view, arbitrary select query) to pull data from. There are some basic table manipulation functions in **dplyr** but I don't believe it is intended to be a tool for doing `update` or `insert` type things in the db. That's just not what that tool is for. Note that the "verbs" implemented in **dplyr** are all focused on pulling data out and summarising (`select`, `filter`, `mutate`, etc.).

If you need to *alter* data in a data base on a row level, you'll need to send SQL queries to a connection created by `dbConnect`. If all you're doing is pulling data from a db and analyzing it in R, that is what **dplyr** is for.

Comment: So if I first need to read some data and then perform a calculation and later write the result to the DB you would suggest to ONLY use dbConnect() ?

Comment: @geoHeil You could do that, but there's nothing stopping you from using **dplyr** to gather and manipulate and then updating via a connection from `dbConnect`.

Comment: so there is no recommended or best practice approach?

Comment: @geoHeil That would depend strongly on one's preferences regarding tools (do you _like_ **dplyr**? do you _hate_ it?), your preferences on coding style (is what you're doing able to be done more cleanly, concisely, more maintainable using one or the other?). And only you can answer those questions.